# How can i create a bootable iso of my current installed system?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, live-usb, iso, livecd

I'm on debian stable and I'm looking for some tools to create a bootable iso of my system, with attached apps installed and personal files, so that I can replicate it on multiple machines.
At the moment, the closest solution I've found is https://www.linux-live.org/, which easily creates a folder to be copied to usb and made bootable.
Unfortunately, due to a bug (already reported), it does not generate an iso, but a folder to be copied to usb.
Is there any other similar tool that maybe just generates an iso?

Comment: There is an [old article](https://linuxgazette.net/113/kapil.html) that may still be modifiable to something that works today!

Comment: If just a few machines, It may be easier to just do new install & restore from your normal backup. If you have a standard desktop, /home & list of installed apps may be all you need. If data in separate data partition or if server apps in / would you need to copy those things also. Only if exactly same hardware may you want some settings in /etc.  Rsync is very fast to restore data. I now have at least one copy of data on external SSD which is perhaps faster than internal HDD. When I used flash drives writes were very slow.